# Null values in json Twitter Search API Php

Tags: php, json, api, twitter

I try parse Search Twitter API results. ID,Nick name, status message etc. - with this all stuff are all ok. But when i try echo hastags or media url i catch null value but in in json i have a data.
My working code:
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

```
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),true);

foreach($string['statuses'] as $tweets) {
 $time = $tweets['created_at'];
 $id = $tweets['id'];
 $source = $tweets['source'];
 $tweet = $tweets['full_text'];
 $name = $tweets['user']['name'];
 $user = $tweets['user']['screen_name'];
 $profile_image = $tweets['user']['profile_image_url'];
 $followers = $tweets['user']['followers_count'];
 $friends = $tweets['user']['friends_count'];
 $listed = $tweets['user']['listed_count'];
$hashtag = $tweets['media']['media_url'];
echo "Time and Date of Tweet: " . $time ."<br />";
 echo "ID of Tweet: " . $id . "<br />";
  echo "Source of Tweet: " . $source . "<br />";
        echo "Tweet: ". $tweet ."<br />";
        echo "Tweeted by: ". $name ."<br />";
        echo "Screen name: ". $user ."<br />";
  echo "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/$user\">@$user</a><br />";
  echo "<img src=\"".$profile_image."\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\" /><br />";
        echo "Followers: ". $followers ."<br />";
        echo "Friends: ". $friends ."<br />";
        echo "Listed: ". $listed ."<br /><hr />";
```

here piace of json output (var_dump $string)

```
 string(46) "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DrvSmRIWkAEDLMv.jpg"
            ["media_url_https"]=>
            string(47) "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DrvSmRIWkAEDLMv.jpg"
            ["url"]=>
            string(23) "https://"
            ["display_url"]=>
            string(26) "pic.twitter.com/r7nAHcjEpA"
            ["expanded_url"]=>
            string(65) "https://twitter.com/KolaSokol1/status/1061673709738565634/photo/1"
            ["type"]=>
            string(5) "photo"
            ["sizes"]=>
```

As i see i have data at media_url, but when i try

```
$hashtag = $tweets['media']['media_url'];
        echo "hashtags: ". $hashtags ."<br /><hr />";
```

I get nothing.

Also when i try do

```
echo "<pre>";
echo var_dump($tweets['media']['media_url']);
echo "</pre>";
```

I get **NULL**.
I am really bad in php, please give me advise, what i'am missing? Thank you for advice.

Comment: Can you try `$tweets['media'][0]['media_url']`?

Comment: I try but the same => NULL

Comment: Oh i get it. works fine if like this `echo var_dump($tweets['entities']['media']['0']['media_url']);`

Answer (score 0):

Its work if do parse like this

```
 foreach ($string['statuses'] as $tweets) {
        echo $tweets['entities']['hashtags']['0']['text']."<hr />";
}
```